# How to get the last record from multiple records which have the same value simultaneously in a given column mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a table called places_log. The schema for places logs is as follows

```
{
      'type': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
        'allowed': ['in', 'out']
      },
      'fence_name': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True  
      },
      'time': {
        'type': 'datetime',
        'required': True
      }
}
```

When a query to get all the documents of this table sorted by fence name and time is made, say the output is as follows

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| fence_name | type    | time      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| abc        | in      | 08:30     |
| abc        | in      | 08:32     |
| abc        | out     | 09:45     |
| abc        | in      | 15:18     |
| abc        | out     | 16:20     |
| abc        | out     | 16:25     |
| lmn        | in      | 12:30     |
| pqr        | in      | 12:40     |
| pqr        | out     | 13:52     |
| pqr        | out     | 13:58     |
| xyz        | out     | 19:43     |
| xyz        | out     | 19:45     |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

I want a query which will return the following result. For each fence, when there are simultaneous ins, I want the latest in and when there are simultaneous outs, I want the latest out.

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| fence_name | type    | time      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| abc        | in      | 08:32     |
| abc        | out     | 09:45     |
| abc        | in      | 15:18     |
| abc        | out     | 16:25     |
| lmn        | in      | 12:30     |
| pqr        | in      | 12:40     |
| pqr        | out     | 13:58     |
| xyz        | out     | 19:45     |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

Basically there is a feature where the user can create multiple fences on the map we will store the times when the user's vehicle enters or exits the fence. Due to some edge cases, we are getting multiple 'in' events simultaneously without an 'out' event which is not possible. So I am trying to come up with a query where I can only take the last 'in' event (when there are simultaneous ins) and take that time as the time when the vehicle entered the fence.
But the vehicle can enter and exit a fence multiple times. So I have to get all those ins and outs also

Doing an aggregation using group and last will not consider ins and outs which are not simultaneous, for the following aggregation

```
     [
      { "$sort": { "fence_name": 1, "time": 1 } },
      {
        '$group': {
          "_id": {
            "fence_name": "$fence_name",
            "type": "$type"
          },
          "time": {
            "$last": "$time"
          }
        }
      }
     ]
```

We will get a something like this

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| fence_name | type    | time      |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| abc        | in      | 15:18     |
| abc        | out     | 16:25     |
| lmn        | in      | 12:30     |
| pqr        | in      | 12:40     |
| pqr        | out     | 13:58     |
| xyz        | out     | 19:45     |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

Here, I don't get the second time the vehicle entered and exited the fence 'abc'

I want to get multiple ins and outs which are not simultaneous.

And even better if I can get something like this

```
+------------+---------+-----------+
| fence_name | in      | out       |
+------------+---------+-----------+
| abc        | 08:32   | 09:45     |
| abc        | 15:18   | 16:25     |
| lmn        | 12:30   | null      |
| pqr        | 12:40   | 13:58     |
| xyz        | null    | 19:45     |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: You can group on fence_name and type and use [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) aggregation to select the record you desire. Offical documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)

Comment: There is an equivalent [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) if you want the opposite

Comment: @AmanB I tried using $group and $last but that didn't give the result I want. I have updated the question explaining what I have done. Pls have a look